# Access Listbox based on value list - sorting on column

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Listbox with 3 columns on an access form which has as it's row source a value list (not a recordset from the db), which is passed as comma seperated string. The third column is a numeric value, and I wish to sort the listbox desc on that third column.

The rowsource looks like this:

```
0,Standard price,1650,
14,Bookings made during Oct 2011,3770,
15,Minimum Stay 4 Nights - Special Price,2460
```

The listbox populates correctly. I just have no idea how to sort the listbox by the third column in this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very rough idea using disconnected recordset:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

slist = "0,Standard price,1650," _
& "14,Bookings made during Oct 2011,3770," _
& "15,Minimum Stay 4 Nights - Special Price,2460"

With rs
  .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  .CursorLocation = adUseClient
  .CursorType = adOpenStatic
  .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
  With .Fields
    .Append "Field1", adInteger
    .Append "Field2", adVarChar, 200
    .Append "Field3", adInteger
  End With
  .Open


  ary = Split(slist, ",")

  For j = 0 To UBound(ary)
      .AddNew
      For i = 0 To 2
          .Fields(i).Value = ary(j)
          j = j + 1
      Next
      j = j - 1

  Next

  .Sort = "Field3"
End With

slist = rs.GetString(, , ",", ",")
slist = Left(slist, Len(slist) - 1)
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly. I was able to make use of your code to achieve exactly what I was going for. Thanks